# how to calculate maximum file size in FAT-16

Tags: file, operating-system

Consider a FAT-16 system with disk block 2KB. How to you calculate the maximum file size that can be stored in the system?

Comment: Using basic math.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAT Specification](http://www.fysnet.net/docs/fatgen103.pdf), bottom of page 33, directly states:

> The maximum allowed file size on a FAT volume is 0xFFFFFFFF
> (4,294,967,295) bytes.

The size of a cluster has nothing to do with the limit on the size of the file.  A cluster chain is only limited to the size of the FAT (File Allocation Table), which should have enough room to hold all clusters of the volume.

Therefore, a file size can be no more than the size of the volume **or** 0xFFFFFFFF bytes in size, which ever is less.